# How to query the servo MBean for Hystrix?

Tags: java, jmx, hystrix, servo

I am able to access the MBeans in JConsole, and they show up like `com.netflix.servo` > `HystrixCommand` > `countSuccess` > (actual commands and their attributes)

I couldn't find any examples on how to query these objects and the values, e.g. the countSuccess, countFailure etc.

The closest I came was `ObjectName o = new ObjectName("com.netflix.servo:name=countSuccess,instance=T6JmxStatCommand,type=HystrixCommand");` which is at https://github.com/n0rad/hands-on-hystrix/blob/master/src/test/java/fr/n0rad/hands/on/hystrix/t6/T6JmxStatMain.java but apparently it doesn't work.

The mbeans were registered via this code: `HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerMetricsPublisher(HystrixServoMetricsPublisher.getInstance());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out there was nothing wrong with the object name as queried. In fact it is the same one found in the JConsole; full syntax shown here on the right in the screenshot:
[image]

Plus, I needed to add a few system properties to the Eclipse run configuration:
`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8700  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8600 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`

Then I can connect using port 8600. In code:

```
package com.awgtek.miscpocs.lognfetch.client;

import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

public class TestJMXConn {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8600/jmxrmi");
      JMXConnector connect = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
      MBeanServerConnection mbsc = connect.getMBeanServerConnection();
     // ObjectName o = new ObjectName("com.netflix.servo:name=countSuccess,type=HystrixCommand,instance=LogAndFetchRestServicePostCommand");
      ObjectName o = new ObjectName("com.netflix.servo:name=countSuccess,type=HystrixCommand,instance=LogAndFetchRestServiceGetCommand");
      Object value = mbsc.getAttribute(o, "value");
      System.out.println("the value: " + value);
      connect.close();


    }

}
```